# Convert pine script to python with nz function

Tags: python, pine-script

I'm trying to convert a pine script to python but I'm confused about the following code because some results are not same with pine script. For example, at the moment, only last 5 values are right, others are wrong. Please check my code.

Pine Script:

```
up=src-(Multiplier*atr) 
up1 = nz(up[1],up) 
up := close[1] > up1 ? max(up,up1) : up
```

converted code:

```
up = src - (Multiplier*atr)

up1 = up.copy()
for i in range(len(up1)):
   if(i>0):
       up1[i] = up[i-1]

for i in range(len(up)):
   if(i > 0 and close[i-1] > up1[i]):
       up[i] = max(up[i], up1[I])
```

Comment: Please help me it does not work rightly

Answer (score 2):

```
def nz(x, y=None):
    '''
    RETURNS
    Two args version: returns x if it's a valid (not NaN) number, otherwise y
    One arg version: returns x if it's a valid (not NaN) number, otherwise 0
    ARGUMENTS
    x (val) Series of values to process.
    y (float) Value that will be inserted instead of all NaN values in x series.
    '''
    if isinstance(x, np.generic):
        return x.fillna(y or 0)
    if x != x:
        if y is not None:
            return y
        return 0
    return x
```

ref. https://community.backtrader.com/topic/2671/converting-pinescript-indicators/3